# How to make remote webdriver execute longer than 15 minutes with selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I currently have my code and script running correctly while being able to get all the data I need scraping.  My goal is to have my script run for hours and scrape a single page by using the webdriver to refresh every minute.  However, this process only works for the first 15 minutes.

I run this on an was EC2 remote instance by running:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444 -sessionTimeout 57868143 &
python3 /home/ec2-user/scraper/football_live.py;
```

to start the selenium server (which runs longer than 15 minutes) and then the script.

Inside my script I have:

```
data, n_games = football_data(driver)
insert_data(cur, conn, data)
time.sleep(60)
driver.refresh()
```

inside a while loop that will run for a long period of time.

This is my webdriver code:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
time.sleep(5)
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

[Here](https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/Keeping+long+Selenium+scripts+alive) is the only thing I have found that is close to what I am trying to do but it is not all that helpful.

I am also considering just trying to run 15 minute loops in the script as a last resort if there is not a way to extend the duration of the webdriver through selenium.

Comment: Can you add clarification as to why it stops after fifteen minutes? I don't see anywhere where it should stop after 15 minutes. What I would do is use crontab to schedule your python code to run every minute. That way it does not need to be a longstanding process. I can provide an answer but need more clarification first before I waste an answer that could be wrong.

Comment: I have no idea why it stops but it is pretty consistent with the 15 minutes.

Comment: Not sure if this is selenium related, I had selenium scripts running over night for 5 hours without any issue. Try using another selenium version, maybe is a problem with the one that you're using right now. Also, maybe EC2 is not allowing you to run more than 15 min.

Comment: EC2 doesn't have any limits, thats why i chose it over an AWS lambda function.  could it be related to the remote webdriver vs regular webdriver?